# ¿Como mover un fantasma dentro de un laberinto hasta cierto punto? ADT Java

Tags: java, array, arraylist, matriz, array-bidimensional

Quiero mover un fantasma por un laberinto que es un arreglo de tipo String, en el cual un 1 representa muro y 0 es camino. El arreglo es el siguiente:

```
                private String [] data = { 
                "1111111111111111111111111111111",
                "1010100010001000100010001000101",
                "1010101110111011101110111011101",
                "1000001000100000100000000000101",
                "1011111011111011101010101011101",
                "1000000000000000001010101010001",
                "1011101010101011111111111110101",
                "1000101010101000000000001000101",
                "1011101011111010101010111011111",
                "1010001000100010101010000000001",
                "1110111011101011111110111110111",
                "1000100010001000001000000010001",
                "1111111111111111111111111111111" 
                };
```

Ya tengo el laberinto graficado pero presento problemas al dibujar y mover el fantasma, ya que se mueve por donde hay un muro, a continuacion les muestro los metodos que tengo implementados y las caracteristicas de la clase Fantasma:

```
         private int xfantasma;
         private int yfantasma;
         private int direccion;

Fantasma(int x, int y){
   xfantasma=x;
   yfantasma=y;
   this.direccion=(int)(Math.random()*4);

}

       public void mover() {
      try{
          switch(direccion){
       case 0 -> {
           if (Character.getNumericValue(data[yfantasma].charAt(xfantasma-1))==0  ) {
               Borrar();
               xfantasma--;//Mover a la izquierda
               Thread.sleep(200);
               dibujarFantasma();
               
           }else{
               direccion = (int)(Math.random()*4);
           }
           break;
         }
       case 1 -> {
           if (Character.getNumericValue(data[yfantasma].charAt(xfantasma+1))==0  ) {
               Borrar();
               xfantasma++;//Mover a la izquierda
               Thread.sleep(200);
               dibujarFantasma();
               
           }else{
               direccion = (int)(Math.random()*4);
           }
           break;
         }
       case 2 -> { 
           if (Character.getNumericValue(data[yfantasma+1].charAt(xfantasma))==0  ) {
               Borrar();
               yfantasma++;//Mover a la izquierda
               Thread.sleep(200);
               dibujarFantasma();
               
           }else{
               direccion = (int)(Math.random()*4);
           }
           break;
         }
       case 3 -> {
           if (Character.getNumericValue(data[yfantasma-1].charAt(xfantasma))==0  ) {
               Borrar();
               yfantasma--;//Mover a la izquierda
               Thread.sleep(200);
               dibujarFantasma();
               
           }else{
               direccion = (int)(Math.random()*4);
           }
           break;
         }
   }
      }catch(Exception error){
          StdOut.print("Error"+ error);
      }
   
       
}
       
       public void dibujarFantasma(){
       StdDraw.setPenColor(Color.MAGENTA);
       StdDraw.filledCircle(yfantasma+0.5,xfantasma+0.5, 0.2);

       }

       public void Borrar() {
       StdDraw.setPenColor(Color.white);
       StdDraw.filledSquare(yfantasma+0.5, xfantasma+0.5, 0.5);
       }
```

Quisiera saber entonces que tengo mal en esta logica para poder solucionar mi problema, si alguien requiere el codigo de la clase laberinto donde se dibuja me lo puede solicitar sin ningun problema

Comment: tu codigo esta incompleto ya que no compila, ve como hacer un [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Mira las otras clases para que lo puedas compilar:

```
      public class LaberintoC {

private String [] data = { 
                "1111111111111111111111111111111",
                "1010100010001000100010001000101",
                "1010101110111011101110111011101",
                "1000001000100000100000000000101",
                "1011111011111011101010101011101",
                "1000000000000000001010101010001",
                "1011101010101011111111111110101",
                "1000101010101000000000001000101",
                "1011101011111010101010111011111",
                "1010001000100010101010000000001",
                "1110111011101011111110111110111",
                "1000100010001000001000000010001",
                "1111111111111111111111111111111" 
                };
        ;
        LaberintoC(String arreglo[]){
 
}


public String getPosition(int x, int y) {
    
        
            String r=null;
            if(Character.getNumericValue(data[x].charAt(y)) == 1){
                r="Muro";
                
            }else if(Character.getNumericValue(data[x].charAt(y)) == 0){
                r= "Camino"; 
            }
                
            StdOut.println(r);
            return r;
    
    }

        public void dibujaLaberinto(){
            StdDraw.setXscale(0, 31);
            StdDraw.setYscale(0, 13);
            for(byte i = 0;i<data[0].length();i++){
                for(byte j =0;j<data.length;j++){
                    int y = data.length-1-j;
                   
                    if(Character.getNumericValue(data[y].charAt(i)) == 1){
                        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
                    }
                    else StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
                    StdDraw.filledSquare(i+0.5, j+0.5, 0.5);
                    


                }
                

            }
            StdDraw.show();
   
      }

     }
```

Clase Simulacion:

```
         public class Simulacion {
         Bag<Fantasma>b1 = new Bag<>();

Simulacion(){
    
    Fantasma f1 = new Fantasma(1,1);
    Fantasma f2 = new Fantasma(1,4);
    Fantasma f3 = new Fantasma(11,11);
    Fantasma f4 = new Fantasma(6,9);

    
    b1.add(f2);
    b1.add(f3);
    b1.add(f4);
    
    b1.add(f1);

}
public void run() {
    try{
          while(true){
      for(Fantasma cantidad: b1){
        
        cantidad.Borrar();
        
        cantidad.mover();
        cantidad.dibujarFantasma();
                    
        Thread.sleep(60);
        StdOut.println("PosicionX:"+cantidad.xfantasma+"Posicion 
      Y:"+cantidad.yfantasma);
        StdOut.println();
        
    }
    }
    }catch(InterruptedException error){
        StdOut.print(error);
    }
  
    
    
    

   }
     public static void main (String[]args){
     String[] data = { 
        "1111111111111111111111111111111",
        "1010100010001000100010001000101",
        "1010101110111011101110111011101",
        "1000001000100000100000000000101",
        "1011111011111011101010101011101",
        "1000000000000000001010101010001",
        "1011101010101011111111111110101",
        "1000101010101000000000001000101",
        "1011101011111010101010111011111",
        "1010001000100010101010000000001",
        "1110111011101011111110111110111",
        "1000100010001000001000000010001",
        "1111111111111111111111111111111" 
        };
   LaberintoC laberinto = new LaberintoC(data);
   laberinto.dibujaLaberinto();
   laberinto.getPosition(0, 0);
   Simulacion simulacion = new Simulacion();
   simulacion.run();

     }



    }
```

Comment: Esto va EN la pregunta. Usaste un campo llamado _Tu Respuesta_ para poner info de la pregunta